# Stop a background process in flask without creating zombie processes

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I need to start a long-running background process with subprocess when someone visits a particular view.

**My code**:

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "10"])
    return "hi\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This works great, for the most part.

The problem is that when the process (sleep) ends, `ps -Af | grep sleep` shows it as `[sleep] <defunct>`.

From what I've read, this is because I still have a reference to the process in `flask`.

Is there a way to drop this reference after the process exits?

I tried doing `g.subprocess = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "10"])`, and waiting for the process to end in `@app.after_request(response)` so I can use `del` on it, but this prevents flask from returning the response until the subprocess exits - I need it to return the response before the subprocess exits.

**Note**:

I need the subprocess.Popen operation to be non-blocking - this is important.

Comment: Try extend `Thread` class and implement your code there... And to close it, use `join` [https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

Comment: Try to rework your project to use Celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/)  or something else that has a robust way of doing background processing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a lot of "poor man's parallel processing" using `subprocess.Popen` and letting it run freely, but that's often leading to zombie problems as you noted.

You could run your process in a thread (in that case, no need for `Popen`, just use `call` or `check_call` if you want to raise an exception if process failed). `call` or `check_call` (or `run` since Python 3.5) waits for the process to complete so no zombies, and since you're running it in a thread you're not blocked.

```
import threading

def in_background():
    subprocess.call(["sleep", "10"])

@app.route("/")
def index():
    t = threading.Thread(target=in_background)
    t.start()
    return "hi\n"
```

Note: To wait for thread completion you'd have to use `t.join()` and for that you'd have to keep a reference on the `t` thread object.

BTW, I suppose that your *real* process isn't `sleep`, or it's not very useful and `time.sleep(10)` does the same (always in a thread of course!)

Comment: The final app is run by nginx and gunicorn, and can have dozens of processes of the flask app. The process that gets launched by subprocess.Popen serves them all with data. I originally tried using threads, but as soon as the original user that opened the page that launched the thread would navigate away from the page, the thread would die and every other process (instance of the flask app) would stop getting served by it. A background process seems to work way better for me than a background thread.

Comment: If this is in production and you have dozens of requests to serve, using Celery as I suggested on the comment is definitely the way to go.

Comment: you mean you used `subprocess.Popen` in a thread already? or just a thread?

Comment: @John so you could try that. But other users suggest a radical change of design using Celery. Maybe it's better. It's your call.

Comment: What does celery do? I've come across the name yesterday, but never dug too deep into it. How would it help?

Comment: Holy crap - launching the process from a thread seems to work. Not sure how I missed the point the first time I read Jean's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - the thread will work, but note Jean's opening statement - this is still a "poor man's parallel processing". My answer does have a brief introduction to Celery. Short of that,  I would have mentioned the thread + subprocess in the thread if this answer was in there already as the "easiest thing to try from where you are" in my answer.

Comment: @jsbueno as frustrating as it may be, OPs usually don't want to throw all their code to the bin when it "almost" works (and I understand them sometimes) and tend to choose the solultion with the minimum impact to their original code, not the best one (industry does that too). Your answer is very good, even if it could frighten people because it involves complex mechanisms. The +1 is actually from me if you hadn't guessed :)

Comment: (there is actually a badge you can get for doing that kind of upvote  :-)  )

Comment: @jsbueno I already have sportsmanship for a while now :) But I only do it when the "concurrent" answer is better/shows outside the box thinking compared to my dumb one :)

Answer (score 3):

As I've suggested in the comments, one of the cleanest and most robust way of achieving this kind of thing in Python is by using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Celery requires a broker transport for messaging, for which  rabbitmq is the default, and at least a process with workers running. However, the thing that increases readbility an dmaintanability is that the worker code can co-exist in the same file or files than your server app. You invoke the remote procedures as though it where a simple function call.

Celery can handle retries, post-task events, and lots of other things for free, everything with mature code hardened by years of use in production.

This is your example after re-writting it for use with Celery:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
celery_app = Celery("test")

@celery_app.task
def run_process():
    subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "5"])

@app.route("/")
def index():
    run_process.delay()
    return "hi\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

With this code, in a system with the rabbitmq server running with default options (I installed the package, and started the service - no configurations whatsoever. Of course on production you would have to tune that - but if everything is to be on the same server, it may not even be needed.)

With rabbitmq in place, one starts the worker process with a command line like: `celery worker -A bla1.celery_app -D`  (pip install celery on the same virtualenv you have your Flask). Then just launch the flask server and see it working.

Of course this has even more advantages if you are doing more work in Python itself than just calling an external process. It can have access to your database models, and you can perform assynchronous actions that modify objects in there (and eventually trigger responses for the user, as "flash" messages on the user session, or e-mails)