# Python create a subprocess and do not wait

Tags: python, subprocess, fork

I would like to run a series of commands (which take a long time). But I do not want to wait for the completion of each command. How can I go about this in Python?

I looked at

```
os.fork()
```

and

```
subprocess.popen()
```

Don't think that is what I need.

Code

```
def command1():
   wait(10)

def command2():
   wait(10)

def command3():
   wait(10)
```

I would like to call

```
command1()
command2()
command3()
```

Without having to wait.

Comment: You could use [asyncio subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html), if you're using Python 3.4+

Comment: If your commands are python functions, you can consider threads: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html . It also depends of what you mean by "I do not want to wait"

Comment: Well ... just remove the "wait" ... sorry. :) Have you looked into `multiprocessing`? You could start a process for every command. The default documentation explains this pretty well.

Comment: @z0rberg's hahahahah! But that would include executing an "external" python script right ?

Comment: @doomyster thanks - taking a look. I mean, I just want to start execution of the method and carry on.

Comment: @PM2Ring great! taking a look!

Comment: No! :D In Linux, it forks the current process and in Windows it just restarts the current one (which means a bit of care has to be taken to make sure it doesn't loop endlessly). Please note that "threads" in python will not necessarily help you have all your code run in parallel, if that's what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 3):

Use python's multiprocessing module.

```
def func(arg1):
    ... do something ...

from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=func, args=(arg1,), name='func')
p.start()
```

Complete Documentaion is over here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

EDIT:

You can also use the Threading module of python if you are using jpython/cpython distribution as you can overcome the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) in these distributions.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: You should fix/clarify your sentence about the GIL.

Answer (score 2):

This example maybe is suitable for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import time

def forked(fork_func):
    def do_fork():
        pid = os.fork()
        if (pid > 0): 
            fork_func()
            exit(0)
        else:
            return pid
    return do_fork

@forked
def command1():
    time.sleep(2)

@forked
def command2():
    time.sleep(1)

command1()
command2()
print("Hello")
```

You just use decorator `@forked` for your functions.

There is only one problem: when main program is over, it waits for end of child processes.

Comment: That is a nice example but it is really just starting to re-invent the wheel on what Python's multiprocessing does  - and if you open the documentation for it, you will find out there are a Lot of things to make it work properly. Starting from the fact that `os.fork` do not work on Windows platform.

Comment: But yes, you've got a very nice and simple example there.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know about multiprocessing module. Only one it gives is cross-platform. Author asked exactly about launching functions with minimal syntax in call time. This way gives it. There is possibility to write code with `multiprocessing` features inside `do_fork()`, and it's better, i agree. But my idea is using decorators for light syntax, it isn't `os.fork()` or `multiprocess.Process()`.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use Python's own [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def command1():
   wait(10)
...

call1 = Process(target=command1, args=(...))
call1.start()
...
```

This module was introduced back exactly to ease the burden on controlling external process execution of functions accessible in the same code-base Of course, that could already be done by using os.fork, subprocess. Multiprocessing emulates as far as possible,  Python's own `threading` moudle interface. The one immediate advantage of using multiprocessing over threading is that this enables the various worker processes to make use of different CPU cores, actually working in parallel - while threading, effectively, due to language design limitations is actually limited to a single execution worker at once, thus making use of a single core even when several are available.

Now, note that there are still peculiarities - specially if you are, for example, calling these from inside a web-request.  Check this question an answers form a few days ago:
[Stop a background process in flask without creating zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448182/stop-a-background-process-in-flask-without-creating-zombie-processes/41448854#41448854)